# How to show commenting user's id in notifications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, notifications

With a little help from my friends I got the user_id to set correctly for `Comment` & `Notification`:

```
[2] pry(main)> Comment.find(8)
 id: 8,
 content: "test",
 goal_id: nil,
 habit_id: nil,
 valuation_id: 9,
 quantified_id: nil,
 commentable_id: nil,
 commentable_type: nil,
 user_id: 1,
 created_at: Thu, 11 Jun 2015 19:57:26 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 11 Jun 2015 19:57:26 UTC +00:00,
 likes: nil>
[3] pry(main)> Comment.find(9)
 id: 9,
 content: "test",
 goal_id: nil,
 habit_id: nil,
 valuation_id: 2,
 quantified_id: nil,
 commentable_id: nil,
 commentable_type: nil,
 user_id: 2,
 created_at: Thu, 11 Jun 2015 19:57:55 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 11 Jun 2015 19:57:55 UTC +00:00,
 likes: nil>
[4] pry(main)> Notification.find(8)
 id: 8,
 habit_id: nil,
 quantified_id: nil,
 valuation_id: 9,
 goal_id: nil,
 comment_id: 8,
 user_id: 1,
 habit_like_id: nil,
 quantified_like_id: nil,
 valuation_like_id: nil,
 goal_like_id: nil,
 followed_id: nil,
 comment_like_id: nil,
 read: true,
 created_at: Thu, 11 Jun 2015 19:57:26 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 11 Jun 2015 19:57:29 UTC +00:00>
[5] pry(main)> Notification.find(10)
 id: 10,
 habit_id: nil,
 quantified_id: nil,
 valuation_id: 3,
 goal_id: nil,
 comment_id: 10,
 user_id: 2,
 habit_like_id: nil,
 quantified_like_id: nil,
 valuation_like_id: nil,
 goal_like_id: nil,
 followed_id: nil,
 comment_like_id: nil,
 read: true,
 created_at: Thu, 11 Jun 2015 20:00:14 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 11 Jun 2015 20:00:30 UTC +00:00>
```

but now the `user_id` still isn't showing the correct id in the partial. All the notifications still say "1 commented on your value" even though the `rails console` clearly shows some say 2.

**notifications_controller**

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:destroy]

  def index
    @notifications = current_user.notifications
    @notifications.each do |notification|
      notification.update_attribute(:read, true) 
    end
  end
```

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_create :create_notification
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :comment_likes   
  has_many :likers, through: :comment_likes, class_name: 'User', source: :liker
  belongs_to :habit
  belongs_to :quantified
  belongs_to :valuation
  belongs_to :goal
    belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true

private

  def create_notification
    @valuation = Valuation.find_by(self.valuation_id)
    @user = User.find_by(@valuation.user_id).id
      self.notifications.create(
        valuation: self.valuation,
        user: self.valuation.user,
        read: false
      )
  end
end
```

**notifications/_notifications**

```
<%= link_to Comment.find_by(notification.user_id).user.id, user_path(Comment.find_by(notification.comment_id).user.id) %> commented on <%= link_to "your value", notification_valuation_path(notification, notification.valuation_id) %>
```

Comment: Why do you update all notifications on each page load? And you shouldn't work with database on View layer. You showed your notification template, but how do you iterate through notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How `Comment.find_by(notification.user_id)` even works?

I think correct ways are (first and second are equivalent):

- `Comment.find_by_id(notification.user_id)`[source](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by)
- `Comment.find_by(id: notification.user_id)`
- `Comment.find(id: notification.user_id)` [source](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class)

---

If you need just user_id why don't you just write this:
`notification.user_id` instead of `Comment.find_by(notification.user_id).user.id`

Comment: Ah you're right `notification.user_id` does work, the problem is the notifications are all being set as `:user_id` for the user whose valuation it is not whose comment it is

Answer (score 0):

It will help if you include `notification.rb`. `comment.user.id` is equal (but less performant) to `comment.user_id` if comment belongs_to or has_one :user. You shouldn't be looking up in the DB in the views, I don't think `Comment.find_by(1)` even works please review your basic Rails concepts.

But responding your original question. The first parameter of `link_to` is the text that is shown, so `... .user.id` shows the user's id rather than the user's name.

Comment: The question literally says "How to show commenting user's name in notifications?" and that he sees "1 commented on your value". That's simply because he is showing the `.id` rather than `.name`

Comment: Leito I more accurately reflected the title name to explicity say `id` but even still changing it to `.name` does not magically show the correct commenting user's name. and Notification.rb has `belongs_to :valuation` and `:comment`

Comment: It's not magically", `.name` will call the name method on that object. What do you see? You gotta help us out here, give us more details! Simplify your answer too, start adopting some of the suggestions given in all answers to improve your code.